# Adding form to .tpl

Tags: theming

This is definitely being called

```
function studiga_theme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {    
    $items['add_property_form'] = array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'template' => 'node--14',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'studiga_theme') . '/templates/node',
    );

    return $items;
}
```

But which should set up the form fields isn't and I have no idea why

```
function studiga_theme_preprocess_add_property_form(&$variables) { 

  // Shorten the form variable name for easier access.
  $form = $variables['form'];

  $form['first_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('First name')),
    );
    $form['last_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('Last name')),
    );
    $form['address'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('Address')),
    );
    $form['city'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('City')),
    );
    $form['state'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => array(
            'default' => 'State',
            '...' => '...',
        ),
    );
    $form['zip'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('Zip')),
    );
    $form['email'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('Email')),
    );
    $form['phone'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('Phone')),
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Submit',
    );   
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem you're solving? Adding forms to templates in the theme layer is usually not the best solution: The theme layer is to control how your site looks, not how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As marcvangend mentioned already, theming functions are not the right place for altering forms.

I suppose you are using Drupal 7 and like to alter a form that has already been added to the node before. In this case you should have a look into hook_form_alter() or hook_form_FORM_ID_alter():

https://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/7

https://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7

These hooks can be used within your custom module to alter forms even before theming takes place. For getting the ID of the form in question, just debug the $formid parameter of the hook_form_alter() while visiting the node.

For adding a custom form to your node you should write a custom module implementing the following hooks:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function MYMODULE_block_info() {
  $block = array();
  $block['mymodule_form'] = array(
    'info' => t('My Form'),
  );
  return $block;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function MYMODULE_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  if ($delta == 'mymodule_form') {
    $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('MYMODULE_my_awesome_form');
    $block['subject'] = t('My Form Title');
  }
  return $block;
}

/**
 * My Form
 */
function MYMODULE_my_awesome_form($form, $form_state) {
  $form = array();

  // define your form here...

  return $form;
}

/**
 * My Form Submit Handler
 */
function MYMODULE_my_awesome_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  // do your magic on the submitted form values in $form_state['values']
}
```

Then you will find the form within **/admin/structure/block** and can add it to the desired page region of your node. Filter the node within the block settings by choosing 'Only the listed pages' under **Pages/Show block on specific pages** and entering your **node/14**.

Comment: I just want to set up a form in node--14.tpl.php and capture what is posted, validate then write it to the database. Simple with PHP and I expect with Drupal if I knew how but I can't even display the form

Comment: For showing a new custom form on a node you should write a small module utilizing blocks.

(1) Use hook_block_info() to define a block.
(2) Use hook_block_view() to define its output.
(3) Return a custom form as output of your block.
(4) Add a submit handler for this form to use the submitted data.
(5) Add the block to your node using structure/blocks and filter to show on your node only.

It's quite an amount of code, so I will add it later to my above reply.

Comment: Please with just say a couple form fields as an example then I can just change it the fields I need as I am totally in the dark at the moment. I am a bit of a Newby

Comment: Don't worry. Noticed that already. ;) Please check my above edits. For a reference of how to define your form fields / submit buttons, I'd suggest https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.

Comment: Right so I need a library called modules under the theme then another library called MYMODULE or whatever I want to call it then is it a MYMODULE.inc file under there?

Comment: You have to create a custom module located within sites/all/modules, not within your theme. For a tutorial about creating modules, please refer to https://www.drupal.org/node/1074360 or https://www.drupal.org/node/1419390.

Comment: Hmm - it shows up under modules but not under blocks

Comment: function add_property_block_info() {
  $block = array();
  $block['add_property_form'] = array(
    'info' => t('Add Property Form'),
  );
  return $block;
}
function add_property_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  if ($delta == 'add_property_form') {
    $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('add_property_property_form');
    $block['subject'] = t('My Form Title');
  }
  return $block;
}

Comment: Did you enable the module? If so, the block should appear as "Add Property Form" within your available blocks. If you added the block hooks after you enabled the module, you might also have to clear your caches.

Comment: Thanks Can you add formatting? I want something like                                                                                                                        
        <div class="full-container">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="">Unique reference</label>
                    <span class="tooltip" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.">i</span>    
                    <input type="text">
                </div>

Comment: The form also needs some tooltips eg                                                                                                                    <span class="tooltip" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.">i</span>   so can you add spans? Thanks

Comment: :) Have a look to the above mentioned Form API Reference: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7. Using 'container' elements (or '#prefix' and '#suffix' attributes), you can achieve the div wrappers. Using an element's '#attributes' attribute, you can add CSS classes and placeholders.

Comment: You can also add custom HTML as your tooltips using the 'markup' element.

Comment: Ah right thanks. I knew about the css classes but the designer has used divs and spans so I thought I had better used the same. You have been a great help - thanks